# Remove characters using re.sub

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove the special characters with the `re.sub()` function, but when I use the `re.sub()` function my replace function stops working.

[image: Excel, import]

My code:
import re
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

```
tabela = pd.read_excel("tst.xlsx")
(tabela[['nome', 'mensagem', 'arquivo', 'telefone']]) 

for linha in tabela.index:
    nome = tabela.loc[linha, "nome"]
    mensagem = tabela.loc[linha, "mensagem"]
    acordo = tabela.loc[linha, "acordo"]
    telefone = tabela.loc[linha, "telefone"]

    texto = mensagem.replace("fulano", nome)
    texto = texto.replace( "value", acordo)
    texto = texto.replace( "phone", telefone)
    texto = re.sub(r"[!!@#$%¨&*()_?',;.]", '', telefone)
    print(texto)
```

Print result:

```
11
```

How it should come out:

```
thyago

R$200

11
```

Answer (score 0):

Loops should be rarely used in Pandas.
Try this:

```
tabela['telefone'] = tabela['telefone'].str.replace(r'[!!@#$%¨&*()_?\',;.]', '', regex=True)    
tabela['mensagem']= tabela.apply(lambda x: x['mensagem'].replace('fulano', str(x['nome'])), axis=1)
tabela['mensagem']= tabela.apply(lambda x: x['mensagem'].replace('value', str(x['acordo'])), axis=1)
tabela['mensagem']= tabela.apply(lambda x: x['mensagem'].replace('phone', str(x['telefone'])), axis=1)
```

Comment: did not work...

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: The colleague there helped me, the formula was:

`texto = re.sub(r"[!!@#$%¨&*()_?',;.]", '', texto)`

Thanks

Comment: I understand, but please note that you should avoid using loops in python. They are very slow

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

repalce

```
texto = re.sub(r"[!!@#$%¨&*()_?',;.]", '', telefone)
```

to

```
texto = re.sub(r"[!!@#$%¨&*()_?',;.]", '', texto)
```

Comment: @Thyago you are welcome, even not @ [myname] 